# Obtaining kernel command line parameters of Android Linux kernel

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I know when an (Android) bootloader starts loading kernel, it passes some parameters to the kernel (for example androidboot.verifiedbootstate, ...), which can be obtained via reading `/proc/cmdline` file, but it could be read only on rooted devices. Was I right ? Is there any other way of getting kernel parameters in non rooted Android devices ?

Comment: If you set up local console application (CoreBot, for example) are you be able to run `cat /proc/cmdline` there?

Comment: I need to do it without any other application. There is no way to interact with bootloader ? I think if we can interact with bootloader that also will be the answer.

Comment: How can you read it `without any other application`? You have to run something like that somewhere to obtain what you need.

Comment: If there will be a such file in the system, or something like that I just can read it in my own application.

Answer (score 3):

In a 'normal' Linux, `/proc/cmdline` is readable by everyone.
Android explicitly removes that read permission from `/proc/cmdline`.

There is no other way to get at its contents because that would circumvent this protection. (And if somebody were to find a way, it would be quickly closed.)

Comment: Thank you for answer. Android kernel makes a lot of constraints compared with the 'normal' Linux kernel. I don't think in this case removing read permission for that file is reasonable. And also (this is not the continuation of my question, but anyway if I'm mistaken please correct me) I haven't found a way to interact with bootloader of Android devices (except fastboot), like an API or some config files of the bootloader. In contrast with 'normal' Linux's bootloader like grub, interaction is straightforward.

Comment: @user422595 If you would notice it's also readable to the group *radio* (maybe not on all devices) which is related to phone modem. I suspect this precautions because */proc/cmdline* has something to do with radio settings and this is administratively prohibited to vary them (FCC, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

On Android 12 (and likely earlier/later versions, but I haven't tested), you can retrieve the kernel command line by taking a [bug report](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report). Bug reports are collected by Android's `dumpstate` command, which can and does read `/proc/cmdline`. Here are the three ways I know to collect a bug report:

1. **From the UI**: In "[Settings > System > Developer options](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options)", either tap "Bug report" directly or enable "Bug report shortcut" and then tap "Bug report" in the power off menu.
2. **From ADB shell**: Run `am bug-report` (or `am bug-report --progress` for an "interactive" report that shows a progress bar) on the device using `adb shell`.
3. **From ADB directly**: Run `adb shell bugreport` from your computer, optionally specifying a filename to save the report as (defaults to `dumpstate-<DATE>.zip`).

The device will take several minutes to collect the bug report. Once it's done (and while it's going if you chose an "interactive" report), it will display a notification.

Once you've collected the report, you need to retrieve it for viewing. If you chose option #3, `adb` has already done that for you and the bug report will be present on your computer as a `.zip` file. If you chose option #1 or #2, there are two ways to collect the report:

1. Share it to an app on your device by tapping the "Bug report #X captured" notification.
2. Copy it to your computer using `adb pull`. Bug reports are saved in `/bugreports/` (which is a symlink to `/data/user_de/0/com.android.shell/files/bugreports/`) on the device.

Regardless of what you choose, you should end up with a `.zip` file containing the bug report. Inside that zip file will be a text file named `bugreport.txt`, `dumpstate.txt`, or one of the preceding with a date appended. That file will contain a lot of information about the system state, including a line right at the top starting with `Command line:` . That line shows the kernel command line.